# How to make token valid as per user using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need one help. I am doing the token based login `Webservice` using PHP and MySQL. Here I am setting the time duration, If no activities are happened within that time interval the code should return the failed status. I am explaining my table below.

> db_user:

```
id        user_id         token                 added_time         

 1           2           aqs234reftgyh         31-01-2018 12:23 PM
```

The above is my table with the required token and date-time for `user_id=2`. Here my need is each time of user action the input will be `user_id=2 and token=aqs234reftgyh`  pass from user end to match with database. If the current user action time is more than `15 min` of token added time then the code will return as `false` otherwise true.

Comment: Add to your `SELECT` something like `WHERE added_time < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - 15 MINUTES`

Comment: You should use a real `datetime` or `timestamp` field in your database instead of storing a string. Now you cannot easily do calculations with it.

Answer (score 0):

calculate the time difference  and if it exceeds 15 minutes then return false

```
$endTime = strtotime("+15 minutes", strtotime($added_date));

$currentTime = strtotime(date("d-m-Y H:i:s p"));


if(round(abs($currentTime - $endTime) / 60,2) > 15){
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think inside table the `added_time` is in `d-m-Y h:i A` format.